# nodejs sendfile html page

Tags: html, node.js

I have this code that allows me to open a HTML page from specific folder, if I use `server.js` to open that HTMLpage so the page it is generating with all the css and jquery files but if I try to move the get statement to the routes folder then the page is generated but without any css and jquery files and I don't know why !

what I did in the server.js for the generation of the HTML page is below which is working perfectly :

```
const folderPath = __dirname + '/public/AppTemplate/src'
app.use(express.static(folderPath))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/AppTemplate/src/index.html'));
});
```

but what I'm trying now is to get  the html page from routes.js :

step 1 :
 I implemented this statement in server.js

```
app.use('/users', require('./backend/routes/profile.routes.js'));
```

step2 :I tried this statement in routes.js with simple modification :D :

```
router.get('/profile', function (req, res) {
  const dirname = __dirname;
  console.log(dirname)
  const newpath = dirname.length - 14;
  const newP = dirname.substring(newpath, dirname.lastIndexOf("/"));
  console.log(newP);
res.sendFile(path.join(newP+ '/public/AppTemplate/src/02-ProfilePage.html'));
});
```

the step 2 is working but I couldn't get all the associated files (jquery css ...) which are located in

```
/public/AppTemplate/src
```

the image of the output is below :
[image]

hope I mentioned everything, 
Best Regards,

Comment: May you also show us the code in `02-ProfilePage.html1`?

Comment: @AvivLo , this is the html Page paths for css and Jquery  https://ibb.co/2Frhy1B
https://ibb.co/Svz0WF1   but why the Index HTML is working ?

Comment: When you say `index.html` is working are you referring to the HTML part or the script part as well?

Comment: So what's your path for all the css and js files? Are all the resources under `/public/AppTemplate/src`?

Comment: Yes they are all under `/public/AppTemplate/src`  see images https://ibb.co/grCfdq1 but I Noticed an error in network console see this image https://ibb.co/yN86yzK

Comment: @AvivLo  translation for the second image   `HTTP404: MISSING RESOURCE. The server found no match for the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - http://localhost:3500/public/AppTemplate/src/css/main.css`

Comment: It't ok, I speak french

Comment: also get this  `GET - http://localhost:3500/users/img/avatar64-sm.jpg` I think I need some of redirection to the public folder for all the html dependencies

Comment: Does it work if you just paste in `http://localhost:3500/public/AppTemplate/src/css/main.css` in the browser?

Comment: result : `Cannot GET /public/AppTemplate/src/css/main.css`

Comment: how about http://localhost:3500/users/public/AppTemplate/src/css/main.css

Comment: same thing I even tried  `http://localhost:3500/users/profile/public/AppTemplate/src/css/main.css` but nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212151/discussion-between-aviv-lo-and-nodegeek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the content in the `02-ProfilePage.html` has an incorrect path.

Check the path in the script tags. If there is a slash it means that it's already in the `/public/AppTemplate/src` which you specified.

For example, `/js/file.js` will actually point to `/public/AppTemplate/src/js/file.js`

Perhaps try adding a `/` in front of your path in the script tag.

Example:

`/css/x/y/z/` instead of `css/x/y/z`

You will have to append a `/` to all the routes in your script/link tag to be able to successfully load the local resources.

You can use the find and replace functionality in your code editor or IDE to speed up the process if possible.